# MySQL - How to select 'DISTINCT' overlapping periods (dates or number ranges)

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, overlapping

Put succinctly, if a query tells me A overlaps B then I don't need it to also tell me that B also overlaps A as they overlap each other.

So I am trying to use a self join in sql to select just 'DISTINCT' overlaps.

To illustrate, here is a simple  SQL fiddle that I wrote to show inclusive overlap selection (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af84f/1)

In detail...

Assume I have a table of name (char), d1 (int), d2 (int) ,  the schema of which is below. Here d1 and d2 represent the start and end of some interval that might overlap with another interval in the same table,.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  letter char ,
  d1 int ,
  d2 int  
) ;
```

Given this table I fill it with some values

```
INSERT INTO test (letter,d1,d2)
VALUES
   ('A',  2, 10),    -- overlaps C and D
   ('B', 12, 20),    -- overlaps E
   ('C',  5, 10),    -- overlaps A and D
   ('D',  1,  8),    -- overlaps A and C 
   ('E', 13, 15),    -- overlaps B
   ('F', 25, 30);    -- doesn't overlap anything
```

and run the following query that uses a self join to correctly find the rows where d1 and d2 in one row has an inclusive overlap with d1 and d2 in other rows.

```
-- selects all records that overlap in the range d1 - d2 inclusive
-- (excluding the implicit overlap between a record and itself)
-- The results are sorted by letter followed by d1

SELECT
  basetable.letter as test_letter,
  basetable.d1,
  basetable.d2,
  overlaptable.letter as overlap_letter,
  overlaptable.d1 as overlap_d1,
  overlaptable.d2 as overlap_d2

FROM
  test as basetable, 
  test as overlaptable
WHERE
  -- there is an inclusive overlap
  basetable.d1 <= overlaptable.d2 and basetable.d2 >= overlaptable.d1
AND
  -- the row being checked is not itsself
    basetable.letter <> overlaptable.letter
    AND
    basetable.d1 <> overlaptable.d1
    AND 
    basetable.d2 <> overlaptable.d2
ORDER BY 
  basetable.letter,
  basetable.d1
```

That correctly gives me the following, showing all 6 versions of overlaps eg left hand column indicates that A overlaps C and another row shows that C overlaps A (note the sqlfiddle doesn't seem to understand field aliases so my column headers are different)

```
test_letter     d1     d2   overlap_letter  overlap_d1  overlap_d2
  A              2     10         D              1         8
  B             12     20         E             13        15
  C              5     10         D              1         8
  D              1      8         A              2        10
  D              1      8         C              5        10
  E             13     15         B             12        20
```

My question is this:

**How can I alter the sql to just get four rows of 'DISTINCT' or 'one way' overlaps?**

ie this result...

```
test_letter  d1     d2  overlap_letter  overlap_d1  overlap_d2 
    A         2     10        D            1           8
    A         2     10        C            5          10
    B        12     20        E           13          15
    C         5     10        D            1           8
```

eg:
 a result that just shows records for A, B and C in the left hand column according to the following reasoning

- A(2,10) overlaps with D(1,8) and C(5,10) and {SHOW THESE TWO ROWS}
- B(12,20) overlaps with E(13,15) {SHOW THIS ROW}
- C(5,10) overlaps with D(1,8)  {SHOW THIS ROW but don't show the A(1,10) overlap as row 2 already shows that A and C overlap}
- D(1,8) {DON'T SHOW anything new as we already know about A(1,10) and C(5,10)}
- E(13,15) {DON'T SHOW anything new as we already know about B(12,20) }
- F(25,30) {DON'T SHOW anything as there are no overlaps}

Comment: You have a table called test, and then you fill a table call testnames. I'm already confused.

Comment: But it seems that you're only interested in situations where one letter is less than another one (as opposed to 'not equal to')

Comment: Change `basetable.letter <> overlaptable.letter` to `basetable.letter < overlaptable.letter`. It will also speed up your query by up to 50 percent. (Which is, now that I can see it, exactly what @Strawberry wrote using words).

Comment: You need a criteria how to choose between (B overlaps E) and (E overlaps B). Besides `basetable.letter {< | > }overlaptable.letter` other possible options are `basetable.d1 > overlaptable.d1' , `basetable.d2 < overlaptable.d2`

Comment: Yes, simply changing <> to < missed the case of A overlapping C (by overlap I include the case of one being entirely inside the other)

Comment: @Strawberry, No, I dont mind if one letter is smaller than another or not, so long as it isn't comparing one record with itself, hence my line 'basetable.letter <> overlaptable.letter'. Also I don't really mind if I get A overlaps C or C overlaps A in the result so long as I don't get both of them. ie only distinct overlaps. The ORDER BY is simply to make the results easy to interpret for this question so the whole post was clear for others to understand

Comment: Yes. You *do* mind!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change to an inequality.  And, you should also use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT basetable.letter as test_letter, basetable.d1, basetable.d2,
       overlaptable.letter as overlap_letter, overlaptable.d1 as overlap_d1, overlaptable.d2 as overlap_d2
FROM test basetable JOIN
     test overlaptable
     ON basetable.d1 <= overlaptable.d2 AND
        basetable.d2 >= overlaptable.d1
WHERE basetable.letter < overlaptable.letter  -- This is the change
ORDER BY basetable.letter, basetable.d1;
```

Comment: Ths misses the case where A overlaps C as it uses the same inequality as suggested in the comments to my original post

Comment: @user3209752 . . . I removed the two of the `where` conditions.  The query looks right to me for finding overlaps.

Comment: That did it. It produced exactly the table I was looking for, even down to the same order of letters. On balance I think I'll make this the correct answer because, although Serg's answer does indeed work to pick up distinct overlaps, the result table doesn't exactly match that requested in my post. Also, by using a join, and a single where clause, this answer is simpler for other people to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This can be as simple as already suggested PK ordering. Alternatively you may wish to introduce lexicographic order of a sort.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  letter char ,
  d1 int ,
  d2 int  
) ;

INSERT INTO test (letter,d1,d2)
VALUES
   ('A',  2, 10),    -- overlaps C and D
   ('B', 12, 20),    -- overlaps E
   ('C',  5, 10),    -- overlaps A and D
   ('D',  1,  8),    -- overlaps A and C 
   ('E', 13, 15),    -- overlaps B
   ('F', 25, 30),    -- doesn't overlap anything
   ('G', 50, 60),    -- a set of equal intervals
   ('H', 50, 60),
   ('I', 50, 60)


SELECT
  basetable.letter as test_letter,
  basetable.d1,
  basetable.d2,
  overlaptable.letter as overlap_letter,
  overlaptable.d1 as overlap_d1,
  overlaptable.d2 as overlap_d2

FROM
  test as basetable, 
  test as overlaptable
WHERE
  -- there is an inclusive overlap
  basetable.d1 <= overlaptable.d2 and basetable.d2 >= overlaptable.d1
AND
  -- require lexicographic order: basetable starts later / finishes earlier / its letter is less then overlaptable
  basetable.d1 > overlaptable.d1 OR (basetable.d1 = overlaptable.d1 
                                     AND (basetable.d2 < overlaptable.d2 OR (basetable.d2 = overlaptable.d2 
                                                                             AND basetable.letter < overlaptable.letter)))
ORDER BY 
  overlaptable.d1, 
  basetable.d2,
  basetable.letter
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to give me the correct 4 rows including the A overlapping C. I'm guessing you are treating 'letter' as the primary key - which was my intention in the small example I gave but I didn't make it explicit for brevity. In the real application I am retrieving people's forenames, surnames and dates that overlap but each person does have a numerical ID as their PK held in the equivalent of my table 'test', so I think your solution will work if I substitute member_ID for letter in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, my guess was  'letter' is the primary key because it's used in your query to exclude  the same row. If member_ID is the PK really, you can safely substitute member_ID for letter.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to develop that 'where' clause Serg, I have given it an upvote. However after consideration I have marked Gordon's answer as correct as it produces exactly the table I was looking for and by using a join is able to use simpler logic.